# Mongoose schema method find does not yield all possible combinations through $and and $or

Tags: javascript, mongoose

For a CMS system with pages I implemented the following interface (excerpt):

```
const pageSchema = new Schema<PageDoc>(
    {
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        children: [
            {
                type: Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Page'
            }
        ],
        hideInMenu: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false
        },
        parent: {
            type: Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Page',
            autopopulate: true
        },
        path: {
            type: String,
            default: function () {
                return '/' + this.label
            }
        },
        readAccess: {
            type: [String],
            required: true,
            enum: Object.values(UserRoles),
            default: [UserRoles.Admin, UserRoles.Editor]
        }
    },
    {
        toJSON: {
            transform(doc, ret) {
                // modify ret directly
                ret.id = ret._id
                delete ret._id
                //delete ret.__v //versionKey: false,
            }
        }
    }
)

// ...

const Page = mongoose.model<PageDoc, PageModel>('Page', pageSchema)
export { Page, PageDoc }
```

with UserRoles being the following enum:

```
export declare enum UserRoles {
    Guest = "guest",
    Customer = "customer",
    Editor = "editor",
    Admin = "admin"
}
```

Now I have the following collection of documents:

- 'Free Content' with readAccess: 'guest', hideInMenu: false, parent: null
- 'Free Article 1' with readAccess: 'guest', hideInMenu: false, parent: 'Free Content' (id of it)
- ...
- 'Member-Area' with readAccess: 'member', hideInMenu: false, parent: null
- 'Member Article 1' with readAccess: 'member', hideInMenu: false, parent: 'Member-Area' (id of it)
- ...

The following Mongoose query is supposed to return all of the above documents, but instead only returns the root pages 'Free Content' and 'Member Area' (with their children pages populated inside), but omits all the children pages as separate entries in the output:

```
const pages: PageDoc[] = await Page.find({
            $and: [
                { hideInMenu: false },
                { $or: [{ readAccess: UserRoles.Guest }, { readAccess: UserRoles.Customer }] }
            ]
        })
            .or([{ $and: [{ parent: { $ne: null } }, { 'parent.hideInMenu': false }] }, { parent: null }])
```

So my question to you is, why is the query not returning also the children pages (which are also single documents in the MongoDB collection) and how to fix the query so that it returns both parents and all its children pages (with hideMenu: false and readAccess both for 'guest' or 'customer')?

---

UPDATE: Due to the autopopulate for the 'parent' the query does not know anything about a parent and thus cannot find the corresponding documents.

I added two more documents:

- 'Hidden-Area' with readAccess: 'member', hideInMenu: true, parent: null
- 'Not hidden Article 1' with readAccess: 'member', hideInMenu: false, parent: 'Hidden-Area' (id of it)

The following query now returns all documents, but it also returns child documents whose parents have the hideInMenu: true :(

```
pages = await Page.find(
            {
                hideInMenu: { $ne: true },
                readAccess: { $in: [UserRoles.Guest, UserRoles.Customer] }
            },
        )
            .populate([
                {
                    path: 'parent',
                    options: { autopopulate: false },
                    match: {
                        hideInMenu: { $ne: true }
                    }
                }
            ])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!